# Azure WebJob is running unreliable

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

We have two environments Test (staging) and Prod (production).
Almost all settings are same, my WebJob is console application based on .NET Framework 4.7.2. It is scheduled to run at 3 AM every day. The only purpose of this WebJob is to call our endpoint on our WebApp.

On Test environment, the WebJob is running as expected – once per day. Because it should call our API, I can use Application insights and search for incoming  requests on this endpoint, it was requested once every day for last 30 days:

[test environment last 30 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKPIr.png)

But on PROD environment it’s little bit more interesting. This is graph for last 30 days for same endpoint that should be called by the WebJob:

[prod environemnt last 30 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8hOe.png)

It was called only two times - more exactly the call to the endpoint was logged in Application Insights only two times.

When I check in the WebJobs section, the WebJob is in Successful state and in the logs I can see:
“[05/23/2019 03:00:12 > 184a66: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success”

This status is logged only after the endpoint is called and it receives 202 OK code, so it must call something, because the job finished successfully.

But one of the first lines processed on the mentioned endpoint is write to our trace log – but there is nothing, the log is empty - this trace log is independent on ApplicationInsights, it's log in our Storage table.

Purpose of this WebJob is to schedule Push Notifications, when I check our Notification Hub on Azure, I can see that something sent scheduled push notifications around 5 AM, which is exactly when the job should run (3:00 in the job log is UTC, the graph is UTC+2)

Why is the request on the endpoint not logged? It had to call it, if it was changed to Successful state.

Why is our trace log empty, if the code was processed and push notifications were scheduled?

Is there a possibility  that it runs on some other instance of our WebApp?

To summarize my expectations:

1. WebJob runs every day at 3 AM

   - no problem with that, it runs as scheduled
2. WebJob should call API endpoint "api/job/endpointname" on AppService

   - I expect this should be logged as incoming request in the Application insights of AppService
   - It's not logged every time, it's random
3. AppService is called on expected endpoint

   - first thing we do is logging this call to our trace log - this trace log is completely independent of application insights, it is our internal log in StorageTables
   - it is not logged here, it looks like nothing ran on the AppService itself - as we have no logs about incoming requests + we   don't have anything in our trace logs
4. Purpose of the endpoint that should be called by the WebJob is to schedule PushNotifications

   - even if we don't have any record that anything ran on the AppService, the Push notifications are successfully scheduled on our push notification hub
   - it almost looks like it runs on some different instance of the AppService, if that's even possible

It seems this problem is occurring on all webJobs that we have, this one is most noticeable. The main problem is that I don't can't track it.

Also, "Always On" setting is set to Enabled.
I also tried to set ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 48, because it was previously only on default (2), didn't help.

Comment: Your two environments, is it one app service with two slots (test, production) or two separate app services?

Comment: Separate app services - it's completely different Directory, different subscription too.

Comment: Since you're deploying to two different services on two different subscriptions, for sanity sake, is your web job using the same app insights instrumentation key that you're using on your production environment/subscription?

Comment: Well, no, it is not using same key as the app insights are not set up on WebJob itself.
I expect the incoming request should be caught by app insights on AppService, and that is happening correctly on test environment.

Comment: If it's using the same instrumentation key, you don't see your production URL set as the Request URL? You only see your test URL as the only Request URL?

Comment: Sorry for late answer - I did not have AppInsights set up on WebJob, only on AppService.
I've prepared AppInsights on WebJob (with same key), including trace logging and waiting until I can release it to production to get some more logs.

Comment: Hi Martin, I wanted to follow up to see if you've had a chance to make a release. Feel free to keep me updated.

Comment: Yes, I have new trace logs and it looks like the job runs every day as scheduled, but it does not log Request to the API every time... 
There is HTTP trace log with right URL, but there is not Request log... I don't know why, I know about sampling, but we should have it set to 100%.
Anyway, I set different time for the WebJob and it runs better, so far it ran 5 from 7 days of the week, so I am happy with that, better than 2 per month.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please feel free to reach back out if you run into any issues in the future.